# Voice call using twilio not telling generated number in call

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am implementing  otp in voice i.e through call using twilio,when user enters his number and click on voice ,he has to get call n play randomly generated 4 digit number. Now the call will be going to entered number but its not telling generated number to verify...URL i used is http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml, which contains some that it was telling in voice....
Please tell me how change this URL so that it tells randomly generated number..

My Java code:

```
public Call sendCall(String mobileNumber, String smsText) {
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 

        // Build the parameters 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", mobileNumber)); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+13122489611"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Method", "GET"));  
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FallbackMethod", "GET"));  
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackMethod", "GET"));    
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Record", "false")); 
        try{
        CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory(); 
        Call call = callFactory.create(params); 

        } catch (TwilioRestException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

how to replace the URl...
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the [URL parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter), ensure that you have a publicly accessible URL that provides some TwiML instructions regarding the logic you wish to produce in your app.

You can do this using [TwiML Bins in the console](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-set-up-your-own-twilio-conference-line-with-twiml-bins.html).